# Disable to purchase product during price 0 or out of stock

Tags: magento-1.9, stock, ce-1.9.2.3

How can I disable to purchase the product during price 0 or out of stock?

Comment: which version are you using?

Comment: magento 1.9.2.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to disable out of stock product to display at front-end. You can disable it from:

```
Admin login >> System >> Configuration >> In catalog tab >> Inventory >> Stock option tab >> Select "No" in Display Out of Stock Products drop down field.
```

I hope this will help you (V1.9.2.2)

Comment: do you know, how to create sample track list in magento

Comment: like this     http://prnt.sc/b0gqj2

Comment: Yes I think, You can create this vie bundle product. Create downloadable product and assign this product to bundle product. For E.g. Hip hop -2007

Comment: i just allow user can hear only sample track, not able to download.

Comment: can i set duration limit from magento back end .